¿Como accedo al navigation object desde el componente que crea el navigator?
Necesito pasar a un componente el navigation object (el que recibo por ejemplo haciendo useNAvigation()) como prop. El tema es que el que me interesa es el navigation de una navegación anidada:
const Stack = createStackNavigator(); //Aca creo la navegación anidada

return (
    <BaseScreen
     navigator={nestedNavigation} //Este es el nav que necesito agarrar/instanciar
     > 
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="addDevice1">
          <Stack.Screen name="addDevice1" component={AddDevice1}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="addDevice2" component={AddDevice2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    <BaseScreen/>

)

Si hago useNavigation(), lo que voy a obtener es el navigation object de la navegación principal, la que me trajo a este componente. Lo que estoy haciendo ahora medio tricky es mandar a travez de un context desde addDevice1 (la primera pantalla que se carga) el navigation que le llega como parámetro de inicialización (... export function AddDevice1 ({navigation}){.... )
Existe algun método o propiedad al crear un stackNavigator que me permita acceder a lo que necesito para no tener que agarrarlo en las Screen renderizadas?
